# Passing multiple variables to Export-CSV in Powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, csv, scripting, export-to-csv

Hey guys I'm having a Powershell 2.0 problem that is driving me crazy. My objective: Create a script that determines the size of the Documents folder along with the current user on the same row, but in two different fields in a csv file. I have tried the following scripts so far:

```
$startFolder= "C:\Users\$env:username\Documents"
$docinfo = Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum |
$docinfo | Export-Csv -Path C:\MyDocSize\docsize.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

This script works and exports the folder size (sum), along with some columns that I don't need, "Average, Maximum, Minimum, and a property column that has "Length" as a value. Does anyone know how to just show the sum column and none of the other stuff? My main question is however, how do I pass  "$env:username" into "$docinfo" and then get "$docinfo" to pass that into a CSV as an additional column and an additional value in the same row as the measurement value?

I tried this:

```
$startFolder= "C:\Users\$env:username\Documents"
$docinfo = Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Select-Object $env:username
$docinfo | Export-Csv -Path C:\MyDocSize\docsize.csv -Encoding ascii - NoTypeInformation
```

This will pass just the current username to the csv file, but without a column name, and then I can't figure out how to incorporate the measurement value with this. Also I'm not even sure why this will pass the username because if I take the "Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse" out it will stop working.

I've also tried this script:

```
$startFolder= "C:\Users\$env:username\Documents"
$docinfo = Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum  
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
UserName = $env:username
DocFolderSize = $docinfo    
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\MyDocSize\docsize.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

This script will pass the username nicely with a column name of "UserName", however in the "DocFolderSize" column instead of the measurement values I get this string: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo

Not sure what to do now or how to get around this, I would be really appreciative of any help! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try"

```
Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum | Select Sum, @{Label="username";Expression={$env:username}}
```

The `@{Label="username";Expression={$env:username}}` will let you set a custom column header and value.

You can customize the Sum column using the same technique:

```
Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum | Select @{Label="FolderSize";Expression={$_.Sum}}, @{Label="username";Expression={$env:username}}
```

And if you want to show the folder size in MB:

```
Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum | Select @{Label="FolderSize";Expression={$_.Sum / 1MB}}, @{Label="username";Expression={$env:username}}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, however if I just select sum it exports to csv as "@{Sum=10915869}" how can I just get the number? Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: never mind it only shows up like that when I try it with my object,
"$startFolder= "C:\Users\$env:username\Documents"
Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum | Select Sum, @{Label="username";Expression={$env:username}} | Export-Csv -Path C:\MyDocSize\info.csv\MyDocSize\info.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation" 

This works perfectly and is much simpler than what I had. Thank you so, so much!

Comment: One more question though, how do I customize the Sum column name?
"Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum | @{Label="MyDocSize";Expression={Select Sum}}, @{Label="username";Expression={$env:username}} | Export-Csv -Path C:\MyDocSize\info.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation"
Throws a "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline" error

Comment: Added to the answer. That should meet your needs.

Comment: If you are still looking at this, is there a way to change sum from bytes to MBs within that expression? You've already helped so much I hate to ask for more, but thanks if you can!

Comment: Thanks again Tim, you were extremely, extremely helpful!

Comment: Having a hard time getting it to limit the sum in MB to 2 decimals, could you help with that as well Tim? Thanks if you're still there!

"$startFolder = "C:\Users\$env:username\Documents"
Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum | Select @{Label="FolderSize";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Sum / 1MB)}}, @{Label="username";Expression={$env:username}} |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append -Encoding ascii -FilePath \\S-2LA03-BHM-01\Deploy\MyDocSize\docsinfo.csv"

This works but takes away the column names for some reason?

Comment: Add parenthesis around the math bits: `"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Sum / 1MB)`

Comment: You're converting to CSV and then skipping the first line. That's removing the headers. Any reason why you aren't using `Export-CSV`?

Comment: I am only able to use PowerShell V1 and I want to append, but only v3 supports append apparently, so "ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append -Encoding ascii -FilePath \\S-2LA03-BHM-01\Deploy\MyDocSize\docsinfo.csv" Is the only way I know to make powershell V1 append a file. Any tips/knowledge you can share with me on this?

Comment: You probably only want to do `Select-Object -Skip 1` if the file doesn't exist. So I'd assign everything prior to that to a variable and then remove the headers only if the file exists.

Comment: Awesome, I will do that, ONE more thing, I promise! Would you happen to know how to avoid contention issues if multiple people are using this script on login? For example if the file is open it wont run and throws a file is in use error. Also not sure what would happen if two people ran the script simultaneously, I know the chances of that are extremely slow as the time window is in milliseconds but still. Thanks so much.

Comment: Not really, other than to create multiple files based on the computername. You could merge them all together after the fact.

Comment: Ok, thank you SO much once again for all your time and help. You were helpful and I learned from you.